# Wrong password authentication works after updating from NodeJS 8.x to NodeJS 14.x

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have a project with old package versions and am trying to update it to the latest.
(I updated the least packages needed to make this project work on NodeJS 14.x)

I updated the NodeJS version from 8.x to 14.x, and also:
-Replaced bcrypt-as-promised with bcryptjs
-Updated bufferutil to latest version
-Updated pg to latest version

I don't know why, but when I try logging into the api, it let's me authenticate with wrong password.

I can't really find the problem, as no errors or anything arise.
I'm suspecting that sequeilize@4 could be the problem, I could try updating that, but if anyone else had this problem, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Examine PostgreSQL's `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, the old bcrypt-as-promised package used .catch block to handle invalid password, but in the new bcrypt, everything needs to be handled in the .then block, based on the result.

Handling invalid password in the then block solved my issue.